# Does applying for an Australia tourist visa from Ireland require a valid IRP stamp until the date of return?

Tags: australia, tourist-visas, ireland

I'm an Indonesian passport holder, working in Ireland under critical skill Stamp 1. I'm planning a trip to Australia from 15 December to around 14 January. The problem is I'm currently trying to get Stamp 4 in Ireland, currently waiting for a letter of support. Best case scenario, I might be able to get a Stamp 4 appointment around mid November. My current Stamp 1 had an extension until 1st January.

The question is, can I apply for an Australia tourist visa now for my trip, using my current Stamp 1? I'm afraid if I'm waiting for my Stamp 4, the visa won't make it in time.

Comment: Do you mean that your Irish visa does not permit you to stay past 1 January?

Comment: Yes, my current Irish visa expires on 1st January. I'm in the process of getting Stamp 4 Irish visa, which if I do get it will allow me to stay on the country until at least 2025. The earliest I can get this Stamp 4 visa is around mid November.

Comment: Is your concern what to enter as your current residence?

Comment: My question is can I apply now with my current Stamp 1 for a trip from 15 December to 14 January? Or do I need to wait for my Stamp 4 go through later on November, then apply for tourist visa

Comment: Why do you think you won't be able to apply? Sorry for all the questions I'm trying to get at where you think the difficulty is.

Comment: Because my current visa expires on 1st January and my trip is until 14 January. Usually other countries require proof that you have residence permit that is still valid until after the trip ends, usually to ensure that you won't linger in the country. I was assuming its the same case with Australia, hence i don't know if I can apply now if my trip ends after my Stamp 1 expires

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for a visa with your Stamp 1.

When asked your visa status answer truthfully and explain as best you can. The immi online form probably has it too but the paper one has the following questions:

> What is your legal status in your current location?

> What is the purpose of your stay in your current location and what is
> your visa status?

The first one has options to tick while the second provides space for a brief explanation. There may be other related questions on the form so go over it carefully.

As to whether that will have any impact on your application and whether it would be better to wait for your Stamp 4 I cannot say.